# Does a lower bounded set always have an infimum?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $A$ be a partially ordered subset of $X$. If $A$ is bounded below, does $\inf(A)$ exist?

Comment: This depends completely on $X$. If $X = \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$, then $A=(0,\infty)\subseteq X$ is certainly bounded from below, but has no infimum in $X$.

Comment: I assume you mean $A$ is a subset of a partially ordered set $X$? As stated, you only imply that $A$ is ordered, not $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume $A$ is nonempty to avoid pathologies.

The statement does not have to be true even in the nice case that the ambient space $X$ is totally ordered:

Let $\Bbb Q^\times$ be the set of nonzero rational numbers, and let $\Bbb Q_{>0}$ be the set of positive rationals; then $\Bbb Q_{>0}$ has every negative rational as a lower bound, but there is no **largest** such upper bound.

When we do not assume the space is totally ordered, three elements suffice: put $X = \{a,b,c\}$, $A = \{c\}$ and set $a \preceq c, b\preceq c$ as the only nontrivial comparisons. Then $a$ and $b$ are both lower bounds of $A$, but since they are incomparable, neither is the largest lower bound, $\inf(A)$ does not exist.

Comment: I think you mean "largest such" LOWER bound. Right?